# Identify last value in list and add condition

Tags: c#, list

Am having a Generic List. am using `Foreach` to Loop through the list and performing my operations. I have a scenario where i need to add condition if the last record of list is Iterated.

What i planned to do ?

I can get the list count and decrement and identify the last record

```
foreach()
{
Count--;   //Where Row is the List Count
if (Count >= 1)
{   
}
}
```

But what is the easier alternative way  i can implement this without count or if ?

Comment: what does it mean "add condition"? Btw you can determine the last by `list.Last()`

Comment: i meant If else as Add condition

Comment: For a lot of these types of questions, you may be able to re-cast the problem such that you need to do something special for the *first* item rather than the *last*. That's a lot easier to deal with if your problem is amenable to such a change (just have a flag that you unset at the end of the loop)

Comment: See e.g. Eric Lippert's [Restating the Problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/13/restating-the-problem.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Eric's final suggestion is to have a bool flag for isFirst instead. and that is the same amount of code and pretty much the same of what the OP already does in his code, just that he checks for last index instead.. same amount of inits and checks though

Comment: Can you apply last item rule after all items cycle?

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain a reference to the last items and check for that in the foreach. I would do this by using the LINQ Last method. Something like this:

```
var lastitem = list.Last();
foreach (var item in list) {
    if (item == lastItem)
        // Do your specific check here.
    else
        // rest of the loop
}
```

Keep in mind though that this piece of code has the following limitations:

1. It only works on reference types and not value types.
2. The same object can only appear once in the list.

I supplied this answer as foreach was used in the question. I myself would as mentioned in one of the comments on the question use an index based loop and reverse the list so I can handle the "specific" case first.

Comment: that could yield funky results on valuetypes and such, if the same value exists in the list more than once, then the first condition will be met more than once..

Comment: Thats true. I will update the anwser to note the limitations :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `if` condition in the loop, but you'll have to use a `for` statement, and it will only let you know if the last element was iterated.
If you need to cancel iteration of your last element this won't be relevant:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    // your operations
}

if (i == list.Count) // means you iterated your last element
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerators have no way of knowing which element they are iterating. Therefore, you will need to use another mechanism involving a conditional statement.

However since you are using a `List<T>` which supports indexing the simplest option is:

```
int finalIndex = list.Count - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == finalIndex)
    {
        // Perform required action
    }
}
```